# SQL Merge Error using Python (import pyodbc)

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I have an error when I am trying to merge and update data into a SQLExpress table I have create:

Error: ('The SQL contains 10 parameter markers, but 5 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
Not sure what I am doing wrong, I can Merge and Update when I use SSMS. But can't get past this parametre error when using this Python code.

```
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
                cols = ', '.join(row.index)
                vals = ', '.join(['?'] * len(row))
                print(cols)
                print(vals)
                #query = f"INSERT INTO {table} ({cols}) VALUES ({vals});"
                query = f"MERGE INTO {table} AS target " \
                    f"USING (VALUES ({vals})) AS source ({cols}) " \
                    f"ON (target.id = source.id) " \
                    f"WHEN MATCHED THEN " \
                    f"    UPDATE SET {', '.join(f'target.{col} = source.{col}' for col in row.index)} " \
                    f"WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN " \
                    f"INSERT ({cols}) VALUES ({vals});"   
                print(query) 
                cursor.execute(query, tuple(row))
                conn.commit()
        
            print(f"Inserted/updated {cursor.rowcount} rows into {table}")

        except pyodbc.Error as e:
            print("Error:", e)

        finally:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
```

the print(cols), print(vals) and print (query) return this in terminal.

```
id, operationId, operation, name, externalId

?, ?, ?, ?, ?

MERGE INTO Activities AS target 
USING (VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) 
   AS source (id, operationId, operation, name, externalId) 
ON (target.id = source.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN     
UPDATE
   SET target.id = source.id,
       target.operationId = source.operationId, 
       target.operation = source.operation, 
       target.name = source.name,
       target.externalId = source.externalId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (id, operationId, operation, name, externalId) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

here is the table and two rows of data
[couple of rows of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFM7b.png)

WHat am I doing wrong?  Cheers in advance Dave

I tried using the SQlalchemy library and also asked good old GPT but didn't get very far.

Comment: read this
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7293/pyodbc-open-source-access-odbc-databases/

Comment: can you try this in your code?: `cursor.execute(query, tuple(row) + tuple(row))`

Comment: The SQL statement has `VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` twice, therefore it expects a total of ten values to be supplied.  But `tuple(row)` contained only five values.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and find a better method to do a bulk merge. Maybe bulk insert the data into a temp table and run one big `MERGE` from that.

Comment: @BaktybekBaiserkeev this worked a treat. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply format `source.*` columns to `INSERT` clause like you did in the `UPDATE` clause. This avoids sending two set of `vals` parameters into query. Also, consider avoiding backslash line breaks for parentheses to concatenate lines:

```py
...

upd_cols = ', '.join(f'target.{col} = source.{col}' for col in row.index)
src_cols = ', '.join(f'source.{col}' for col in row.index)

query = (
    f"MERGE INTO {table} AS target "
    f"USING (VALUES ({vals})) AS source ({cols}) "
    "ON (target.id = source.id) "
    "WHEN MATCHED THEN "
    f"    UPDATE SET {upd_cols} "
    "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN "
    f"INSERT ({cols}) VALUES ({src_cols});"
)

...
```

Comment: Parfait, This also worked a treat, thank you to both